# Covariant return type implementation

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

I'm trying to implement a covariant return type for a method in Scala. Let's assume we have the following scenario:

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Cat extends Animal

abstract class M[-T]{
  def get[U <: T](): U
}

val container = new M[Animal] {
  override def get[U <: Animal](): U = ???
}
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Why do you need this? How are you going to use this? By "implementing a type" do you mean implementing a method?

Comment: You tell me, how would you create any animal that the user request? Those kind of signatures are impossible to implement like that, you usually require some factory typeclass or something.

Comment: I'm just curious. And yes, I mean implementing the method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just curious, for example you can use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
import shapeless.{Generic, HNil}

def get[U <: Animal]()(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[U, HNil]): U = 
  generic.from(HNil)

get[Dog] // Dog() for case class, Dog@34340fab otherwise
get[Cat] // Cat() for case class, Cat@2aafb23c otherwise
get[Nothing] // doesn't compile
get[Null] // doesn't compile
get[Cat with Dog] // doesn't compile
```

Or you can use a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def get[U <: Animal](): U = macro getImpl[U]

def getImpl[U: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"new ${weakTypeOf[U]}"
}
```

Or you can use [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime

def get[U <: Animal : TypeTag](): U = {
  val typ = typeOf[U]
  val constructorSymbol = typ.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val runtimeMirror     = runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol       = typ.typeSymbol.asClass
  val classMirror       = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
  val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
  constructorMirror().asInstanceOf[U]
}
```

(see also example with Java reflection in **@KrzysztofAtłasik**'s answer.)

Or you just can introduce a type class and define its instances manually

```
trait Get[U <: Animal] {
  def get(): U
}
object Get {
  implicit val dog: Get[Dog] = () => new Dog
  implicit val cat: Get[Cat] = () => new Cat
}

def get[U <: Animal]()(implicit g: Get[U]): U = g.get()
```

Comment: Technically speaking neither answer implemented the exact signature provided by OP :) - Anyways, excellent answers as always.

Comment: Are there any sources where one could read more about these types of situations (narrowing down a contravariant type so that it can be used in a method)?

Comment: @atos I'm afraid this is too wide formulation.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use reflection to create new instances. You just need to get implicit `classTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Cat extends Animal

abstract class M[-T] {
  def get[U <: T](implicit ct: ClassTag[U]): U
}

val container = new M[Animal] {
  override def get[U <: Animal](implicit ct: ClassTag[U]): U =
    //it gets no argument constructor so obviosly it will only work if your classes has no params
    ct.runtimeClass.getConstructor().newInstance().asInstanceOf[U]
}

container.get[Dog]
```